# Two keywords with the same data

Tags: android

I'm trying to have two keywords with the same result, please help thanks.
Here's the code:

```
if (et2.getText().toString().trim().equals("Good Evening"))                   
{
    tv.setText("Naimbag a sardam");
    tv2.setText("Naimbag a sardam");
    tv3.setText("Maupay nga gab-i");
    tv4.setText("Maayong gabii");
    tv5.setText("Mayap a bengi");
}
```

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this even a question? If it is I believe its to little code.